# Kivy - unable to load image with mqtt on_message

Tags: python, image, kivy

I am trying to use paho mqtt on_message to handle change of images and values when new subscribed message comes through.
I am able to change the text/value and color but unable to change the image.
The image is found by Kivy, error shows in terminal when purposely put wrong directory.
When image is loaded a black box replaces the default image but not the actual image.

The default image loads as normal from its relating .kv file, if image change in main.py is commented out.

Do I need to pre-load images after the MyKivyApp on_start() or is this function not possible?

Main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyKivyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        "list of kv files and returns mainscreen"

    def on_start(self):
        "methods for mqtt message handling"

        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            app = MDApp.get_running_app()
            topic = msg.topic
            value = msg.payload
            value = str(value.decode('UTF-8'))

        #Living Room messages
            livingroom = app.root.get_screen("livingroom").ids

            if(topic == "/livingroom/floor_lamp"):
                if value == "0":
                    livingroom.img_livingroom_floorlamp.source = "./images/floor_lamp-off.png"

MyKivyApp().run()
```

[Image of the black box in the app of where image is apparently loaded to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqcyK.png)

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder, is this more suitable. Sorry, this is my first post so I am unclear how I can make more relatable.

Comment: as per @ApuCoder,  where does `MDApp` come from please ?

Comment: @D.L, updated code to show the MDApp is import from kivymd.app.

Comment: In your code you are setting `livingroom` to `app.root.get_screen("livingroom").ids`, and then using it as `livingroom.ids.img_livingroom_floorlamp.source`. So you are essentially doing `app.root.get_screen("livingroom").ids.ids.img_livingroom_floorlamp.source`. Note the `.ids.ids` above. Try removing `.ids` from `livingroom = app.root.get_screen("livingroom").ids`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, i tried removing .ids but still same problem. I have updated code to reflect latest situation

Comment: Not enough information. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This issue is resolved. Found that by placing "@mainthread" above the mqtt on_message method images will now be updated by kivy when new message is published by mqtt broker.